# how to debug ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, debugging

I try to log value of ModelMultipleChoiceField

```
logger.debug("names %s" % self.fields['names_list'])
```

But I got

```
  2016-08-09 17:00:19,027 DEBUG views names <django.forms.models.ModelMultipleChoiceField object at 0xa74d0bcc>
```

The expected result is sth like:

```
  2016-08-09 17:00:19,027 DEBUG views names [33,40,45]
```

**update**
I'm not sure what is unclear - I suppose, that you want to see the model, but i think is useless - i don't need any value just pk of instances which are selected in ModelMultipleChoiceField

I need to debug because when I enter form i set some hidden fields:

```
<input id="id_names" name="names" type="hidden" value="[33]" />
```

and I'm trying to set it using additional field (using ModelMultipleChoiceField)  - during clean I'm veryfing  checkings and set values. But it looks like ModelMultipleChoiceField is empty in clean, so I want to debug if it's true.

(I have to rename field names into names_list because you may think that hidden field and multiplechoicefield have the same names)

Comment: You need to show a bit more context. We've got no idea where you are calling `logger.debug` from.

Comment: I knew the solution - I totally forgotten, that i'm in clean method, so I can use self.cleaned_data['names'] - which isn't exactly what I want, but for debugging is enough

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `ModelMultipleChoiceField` to a list of strings with

```
selected_names = [label for value, label in self.fields['names'].choices if value in self['names'].value()]
logger.debug("names %s" % selected_names)
```

Comment: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int

Comment: Wait, why you use self['names'] shouldn't be self.fields['names']